# Toggle filtered results in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

How can I filter on first click and then reset filter on second click ? I want to show items having images first and then reset filter on second click.
Please check [fiddle][1]
     [1]: http://jsfiddle.net/6L7xn/9/
Thanks

```
  <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="myFilter = {'largeImage': {'hasImage': 'Yes'}}">Images</button
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have forked your jsfiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/jkrielaars/n5q9xeej/2/

There were a few things I had to change:

- your original filter was checking for hasimage:Yes (with a capital).
  In your objects the yes was all lowercase
- in order to enable "deep filtering" you need to pass `:true` to the filter as third param
- I made a toggle function that toggles the myFilter object between '{}' and the thing you wanted to filter on.

Controller:

```
    $scope.myFilter = {};
    $scope.toggleFilter = function(){
        if(angular.equals({}, $scope.myFilter)){
            $scope.myFilter = {'largeImage': {'hasImage': 'yes'}};
        }else{
            $scope.myFilter = {};
        }
    }
```

And the view:

```
    <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="toggleFilter()">Images</button>

    <div class="item-sc" data-ng-repeat="d in things | filter:myFilter:true">
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple enough to add a function to set a scope variable in your controller that you can call from ng-click.  Then set your filter to equal the value in the scope variable.  Like this:

**Add to controller**

```
$scope.myFilter = 'no' // or whatever you want to default to;
$scope.setMyFilter = function(){
    $scope.myFilter = $scope.myFilter === 'no' ? 'yes' : 'no';
};
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="MyApp">
<div class="container" ng-controller="sentCtrl">
    <div class="row">
        <div><strong>Only show:</strong>&nbsp;
            <div class="btn-group btn-group-xs">
                <button class="btn btn-primary" ng-click="setMyFilter()">Images</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row content-sc">
        <div class="item-sc" data-ng-repeat="d in things | filter: {largeImage.hasImage: myFilter}">
             <h4>{{d.NAME}}<br/><small>ID: {{d.ID}}</small></h4>

        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```